# How to tell which third-party Java libraries are using Log4j 1.x?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, noclassdeffounderror, rjb

To address [CVE-2019-17571](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-17571) flagged by a client I'm trying to upgrade Log4j 1.2.x used within our jfreechart-based Rails application to Log4j 2 (following the instructions [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html)). However, I couldn't tell which Java library is still using the old Log4j 1.x imports. Here's the error I'm seeing in Rails log (the Java charting application is loaded via [RJB](https://github.com/arton/rjb)):

```
$ tail -f production_log.2020-03-29

FATAL 2020-03-29 16:58:49 30512 NoClassDefFoundError (org/apache/log4j/Logger):
  lib/chart_interface.rb:24:in 'method_missing'
  lib/chart_interface.rb:24:in 'createChart'
  app/controllers/dash_controller.rb:565:in 'resources_info'
```

Is this a good way to find out which third-party Java libraries are using the old Log4j 1.x imports?

```
$ ls -ltr
total 8756
-rw-r----- 1 root  ainet  391430 Oct  5 02:16 log4j-1.2.15.jar.old
-rwxr-x--- 1 root  ainet 1801249 Mar 26 03:15 wig.jar
-rwxr-x--- 1 root  ainet  288911 Mar 26 03:15 tcommon-2.1.jar
-rwxr-x--- 1 root  ainet  657841 Mar 26 03:15 postgresql-9.4-1202.jdbc42.jar
-rwxr-x--- 1 root  ainet 1702810 Mar 26 03:15 log4j-core-2.13.1.jar
-rwxr-x--- 1 root  ainet  292243 Mar 26 03:15 log4j-api-2.13.1.jar
-rwxr-x--- 1 root  ainet 1425744 Mar 26 03:15 jfreechart-1.0.13.jar
-rwxr-x--- 1 root  ainet   62103 Mar 26 03:15 commons-pool-1.3.jar
-rwxr-x--- 1 root  ainet  121757 Mar 26 03:15 commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ainet ainet  330507 Mar 26 03:50 jcommon-1.0.24.jar

$ grep -R apache\.log4j
Binary file log4j-1.2.15.jar.old matches
```

The only hit was in the old jar file and yet [RJB](https://github.com/arton/rjb) is complaining about `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: Why don't use just use the Log4j 1.x bridge? The CVE-2019-17571 vulnerability is about a SocketServer class, so using the bridge is fine.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to try that next if removing Log4j 1.x entirely from the application doesn't work. But I need to know which libs are still referencing the old Log4j.

Comment: Guessing here, but the error says that it has something to do with `createChart`, you're using a `jfreechart-1.0.13.jar` library, so that's probably it.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to modify third party libraries so you will almost certainly end up needing the log4j-1.2-api jar.

Comment: have you looked at ruby general configuration yet?  there can be config.dependency_loading or config.logger that helps you. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.0.1/configuring.html